# New mark ^ in package.json file

Tags: npm, versioning, package

After last npm update, i found that some package versions started with `^`. I can't found any information about it, because of filtering suck signs by search engines. So, it looks like:

```
"grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.4.2",
"grunt-bower-install": "^0.7.0",
"grunt-concurrent": "^0.4.3",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
```

Some, are old `~`. I will be grateful for any likes or information about that.

I have a suggestion that it indicates witch packages was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The caret, [...] will update you to
>   the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match
>   any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.

http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/

Comment: Thanks! Accept in 10 minutes.