# karma problems while trying to set up an angular project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to set up an environment that supports angular/coffeescript/sass/jade.. and was told [angular-curve](https://github.com/kenhkan/angular-curve) does an excellent job.

I get stuck at this part: after cloning the repo and running `npm install` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.5.4 wants karma@~0.9.4 || ~0.10
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.11.14
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/abdullah/dev/js/sandbox/bayt
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/abdullah/dev/js/sandbox/bayt/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

see the output of my `npm ls` [here](http://pastebin.com/zKLrDMUM), and `npm ls global` returns empty.

Coming from a rails/bundler background, and [reading](http://www.quora.com/npm/How-does-npm-compare-to-other-packaging-systems-like-Ruby-gems-and-Pythons-pip) that npm allows for nested dependencies (ie you can have 2 libraries having each one dependency in different versions) i don't see why/how this problem is happening. Help anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `karma` version in `package.json` to `"karma": "^0.9.0"` or `"karma": ">=0.9.0"` and make `npm update`

**Update**

Also try to update `grunt-karma` too. I just tried and it wasn't work with previous changes. So, as you mentioned: `"grunt-karma": ">=0.5.0"`, `"karma": ">=0.9.0",` and `npm update`.

Actually i usually remove all versions from such outdated `package` files and do `npm update`, cause eventually you have to update them (kinda newbie thing perhaps, and not recommended). So, if previous doesn't help, you can try this. Last time i have only one small problem with newest versions.

Before that you can also type `npm cache clean` in console.

Comment: what does the `^` mean?

Comment: That update minor version, like `0.x.x`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931310/new-mark-in-package-json-file

Comment: i changed the karma to `"karma": ">=0.9.0"` and even changed `grunt-karma` to `grunt-karma: ">=0.5.0"` but i still get the *exact* same error?

Comment: For me it works with `"karma": "^0.9.0"`, i haven't changed `grunt-karma` version.

Comment: And do `npm update`, i also remove `node_modules` folder just in case

Comment: so you have been using this exact same library before? or did you just install it right now?

Comment: I've just clone it and had the same error, then change karma version, and it works. I'm using the latest versions in my projects.

Comment: i see.. well bear with me i got a really slow connection.. i'll give u the correct answer when it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54370/discussion-between-zishe-and-abbood).

Comment: can you paste your package.json in a gist or something please?

Comment: For me it works with this https://gist.github.com/zishe/e40ecbecceb528b6f17f (after `npm update --save`)

Comment: No, did you miss `bower install`?

Comment: but my bower_components directory is inside my app directory.. where do you have it?

Comment: no, it's in application root, in `angular-curve` for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54577/discussion-between-abbood-and-zishe).